# Form differences in QT between Windows and Linux

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created an application using PyQt5 which runs well on both Windows and Linux but for one form.  I am trying to figure out why the form displays appropriately on Windows but not on the Linux systems.

The first form is a simple login form which I made using Designer.  It has a vertical layout and a grid layout for the fields.  It looks like this in designer.

[image: Qt Designer]

This looks fine in windows:

[image: Windows]

But in Linux Mint 17.03, the fields are squashed and are an incorrect height:

[image: Linux Mint login screen]

It is similar in Unbutu 14.04:

[image: Ubuntu login screen]

My code to open the form looks similar to this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from login import *
import csv


class Login(QDialog):
    """User login """
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_login_form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(lambda: self.handle_login(servers=servers))
        servers = {}
        with open('servers.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
            server_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in server_reader:
                self.ui.cbo_db_name.addItem(row[1])
                servers[row[1]] = (row[0],row[2],row[3])


    def handle_login(self, servers=''):
        the_key = self.ui.cbo_db_name.currentText()
        self.server = servers[the_key][0]


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    access = Login()
    access.exec_()
    print(access.server)

    myapp = Test_form()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code for the form from Qt designer looks like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_login_form(object):
    def setupUi(self, login_form):
        login_form.setObjectName("login_form")
        login_form.resize(223, 129)
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(login_form)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 198, 105))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.password, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.username = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.username.setObjectName("username")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.username, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.cbo_db_name = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.layoutWidget)
        self.cbo_db_name.setObjectName("cbo_db_name")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.cbo_db_name, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.layoutWidget)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.label.setBuddy(self.username)
        self.label_2.setBuddy(self.password)

        self.retranslateUi(login_form)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(login_form.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(login_form.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(login_form)
        login_form.setTabOrder(self.username, self.password)
        login_form.setTabOrder(self.password, self.cbo_db_name)

    def retranslateUi(self, login_form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        login_form.setWindowTitle(_translate("login_form", "Please log in..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("login_form", "User name:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("login_form", "Password:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("login_form", "Database:"))
```

Comment: Actually, the Windows fields are pretty small in terms of height. The field should be as high as the button if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your UI file in Qt Creator, right click the dialog area and select `Lay out` and select either `Lay Out Vertically` or `Lay Out Horizontally`.

This should allow the content of the dialog to be able to "stretch" to the full size of the login dialog.

[image]

Comment: I broke the layout and applied it again as you suggested.  I am not sure what I did previously but there was a vertical layout.  I am grateful for your prompt answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much!